# Artifactory search: REST API returns results but web search doesn't

Tags: rest, artifactory

Try searching for any classes here, e.g. use the string ReportJobMailNotification*

https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/webapp/#/search/archive/

It returns no results. Sometimes (seemingly in a random way) it comes up with a warning "Method Not Allowed".

But if you do the same search via REST API you get consistently many results:

https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/api/search/archive?name=ReportJobMailNotification*

Any specific reasons why this might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work now. I guess it was a temporary glitch...